# Color de fondo en xml ANDROID

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de codigo

Boton XML

```
  <Button
            android:id="@+id/strBtnAssociateDevice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_borderCustom"
            android:onClick="GoToConfirmationNumber"
            android:text="@string/activity_login_loginButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            />
```

El xml del android:background es

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="00dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"
        />

</shape>
```

donde lo utilizo para ponerlo en un boton en cual me genera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me gustaría es poder dejar el fondo del boton en rojo completo ,

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html) para eso, aplicando estilos en los cuales defines cómo quieres tus botones. [Mira esta respuesta por ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36666660/5587982).

Comment: Si cambias el solid del shape al color #FF0000 y quitar el stroke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El atributo `solid` indica el color de fondo de tu `shape`, en el código que muestras lo tienes en blanco, asumiendo que `@color/colorAccent` sea el rojo entonces podrías hacerlo de esta manera:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="00dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"
        />

</shape>
```